# Couldn't find atom-live-server

Tags: installation, atom-liveserver

I'm struggling to get live server on atom. I head to the packages section and search for the live server but it does not exist at all. Currently the version I'm on is 1.60.0 . Anyone have similar problem to me?

I tried reinstalling atom as well but no help from that. Check on youtube but still no solution